# Excel VBA Page Pagination, FOR LOOP not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a For Loop to extract some data from a site, with some code for page navigation through the pages. The problem I am having is that the that after the code navigates to the next page the For Loop is not extracting anything.

**What works**

- The FOR LOOP works fine on the first page
- The page pagination code works fine on navigating to the next page/s.

**The Problem**
*

- Once the code has navigated to the next page the FOR LOOP is NOT
  working, it will extract NO data.

I cannot work it out

This is what I am working with minus my code as it was a bit too long

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
Dim Html As HTMLDocument
Dim objIE As Object
Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link
Dim pageNumber As Long ' page no.
Dim nextPageElement As Object 'page element
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim HtmlText As Variant ' for html data

Dim wsSheet As Worksheet ' WorkSheet
Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
         Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")

'+++++ Internet Explorer ++++++
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer 'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
        objIE.Visible = True 'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.navigate Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value & Replace(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2") & Range("C2").Value, " ", "+") 'navigate IE to this web page

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy

y = 2

    Set Html = objIE.document
        Set elements = Html.getElementsByClassName("sresult lvresult clearfix li shic") ' parent CLASS

    'FOR LOOP
    For Each element In elements
      DoEvents

'############################ My code here #################


'COUNTER AND NEXT ELEMENT
y = y + 1
Next element

' #################### START OF Page Navigation will delay ###############
Do
        'Number Of Pages to navigate come from sheet3 - D2
        If pageNumber >= Replace(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D2").Value, " ", "+") Then Exit Do
            Set nextPageElement = Html.getElementsByClassName("gspr next")(0)
                If nextPageElement Is Nothing Then Exit Do

            'Random delay from Max number entered in Sheet3 E2
             Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Application.RandBetween(1, Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E2").Value))
             nextPageElement.Click 'next web page
             Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

            'SECOND Random delay from Max number entered in Sheet4 f2
             Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Application.RandBetween(1, Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("F2").Value))
            Set Html = objIE.document
                pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
Loop

' ########################## End of Page Navigation with Delays ###############

objIE.Quit ' end and clear browser
Set ie = Nothing
Set htmlDoc = Nothing
Set nextPageElement = Nothing
Set div = Nothing
Set link = Nothing

MsgBox "All Done"

End Sub
```

I tried to add this to the end of ***"pageNumber = pageNumber + 1"*** to see if it would work but got not luck

```
            pageNumber = pageNumber + 1

   Set elements = Html.getElementsByClassName("sresult lvresult clearfix li shic")
      For Each element In elements
        DoEvents
           Next element
```

Comment: What is the webpage url?

Comment: its ebay.co.uk, it comes off sheet3 A2, product from B2, and the end of the url from C2. The page navigation works fine, just nothing is extracted from 2,3,4,5, page and so on

Comment: Just presume, the For ... Next loop works fine. Did you check the count of the `Elements`? If the loop does call each element, and there are indeed more than one element, and extracts nothing then the cause would be in the code that does the extraction. That's the part of code you don't share.

Comment: The only work around I have found is to put a copy of my FOR EACH Loop code, starting from  `Set Html = objIE.document` after the `pageNumber = pageNumber + 1` and between the `Loop` of the page navigation. This then re-runs the FOR EACH loop for as many pages as I need. Also within the loop I included the `y = y + 1` & `Next element`. Not the best but it works. Thanks to every one who contributed